# sharepoint 2010. Include javascript in code for all item display forms

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have javascript which can hide empty fields from sharepoint display form.
http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/hide-empty-rows-in-dispform/

I need to add programmatically this javascript to all display forms. 
I dont know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` loops through all elements which matches a specific selector. If the code below is not sufficient, change the selector (`"td.ms-formbody"`) such that your desired elements are matched.

```
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function(){ /* Should walk through all elements */
var val = $(this).text().replace(/\s|\xA0/g,'');
    if($(this).parents().html().match('FieldName="#H#')==null){
        if(val.length==0){
            $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

If you're still stuck, provide your HTML code, so that a more specific answer can be offered.

Comment: I know what this javascript does. I dont know how to add programmatically this javascript to all display forms?! To make it work it should be added to page...

Comment: Rephrase your question and show the source code of your file.

Comment: I have javascript file with code which you mentioned. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom template file, overriding the ordinary DefaultTemplates.ascx (under ControlTemplates).

1. Create _NewTemplates.ascx file (empty). It should go under ControlTemplates as well
2. Copy all the Register stuff from the original ASCX
3. Add the ListForm template copied from DefaultTemplates.ascx (you might need to add a couple more template, depending on the list types you want to support)

Now edit the rendering template to add your JS

<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="ListForm" runat="server"">

<Template>

--> add your code here

<script language="javascript">add functions or hook up enternal JS file</script>

--> continue original markup from this point

Save the file and run IISRESET, that's it